# Spring @PropertySource using YAML

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot allows us to replace our `application.properties` files with YAML equivalents. However, I seem to hit a snag with my tests. If I annotate my `TestConfiguration` (a simple Java config), it is expecting a properties file.

For example this doesn't work:
`@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-test.yml")`

If I have this in my **YAML** file:

```
db:
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@pathToMyDb
  username: someUser
  password: fakePassword
```

And I'd be leveraging those values with something like this:

```java
@Value("${db.username}") String username
```

However, I end up with an error like so:

```java
Could not resolve placeholder 'db.username' in string value "${db.username}"
```

How can I leverage the YAML goodness in my tests as well?

Comment: Define "doesn't work." What's the exception/error/warning?

Comment: Spring Boot flattens the YAML file so it appears as a property file with dot notation. That flattening isn't happening.

Comment: And just to confirm, this works in non-test code?

Comment: Yes. Here is a doc explaining http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot-actuator/README.html#toc_5 and a ways down the page is says 'Note that the YAML object is flattened using period separators.'

Comment: I know it works in general. :) I meant to confirm that this is somehow test-specific and that YAML-based properties are working in the remainder of your project. There's better info here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot/README.html ... there shouldn't be anything test-specific in the YamlPropertySourceLoader, but I haven't tried this stuff yet.

Comment: Oh, yes. I have SnakeYAML on the classpath, so my other YAML are working.

Comment: SpingBoot said it can not load YAML with PropertySource: 24.6.4 YAML shortcomings

YAML files can’t be loaded via the @PropertySource annotation. So in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a properties file.

Comment: please see my answer: have suc pic: if you need project info,please upvote me.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml/66641155#66641155

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Spring-boot has a helper for this, just add

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

at the top of your test classes or an abstract test superclass.

Edit: I wrote this answer five years ago. It doesn't work with recent versions of Spring Boot. This is what I do now (please translate the Kotlin to Java if necessary):

```
@TestPropertySource(locations=["classpath:application.yml"])
@ContextConfiguration(
        initializers=[ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer::class]
)
```

is added to the top, then

```
    @Configuration
    open class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        open fun propertiesResolver(): PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {
            return PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
        }
    }
```

to the context.

Comment: dont forget PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Comment: @KalpeshSoni indeed, without said Configurer, it won't work.

Comment: I had to add the initializer to @SpringJunitConfig instead
`@SpringJUnitConfig(value = {...}, initializers = {ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class})`

Comment: @OlaSundell out of curiosity, why you wrote it does not work with the recent versions of Spring Boot?. I used your solution with 2.3.4.RELEASE and it works.

Comment: Are you sure @TestPropertySource(locations=["classpath:application.yml"]) is required? ConfigFile initializer will search in default locations on its own. I wonder if non default file location would work this way..

Comment: It's too much trouble. see this. easy to use:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml/66641155#66641155

Comment: on the latest versions `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` has been replaced for `ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer`.

This conf worked for me : 

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = { AnalyzerApplicationProperties.class })
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

Comment: **This is wrong answer: it works accidentally ))**. `TestPropertySource` doesn't support YAML and Spring devs refused to implement support. The key is `ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer` or `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer`: they activate regular Spring Boot loading sequence, like taking `application.yml` from classpath. You can control the name of files indirectly via `@ActiveProfiles`.

Answer (score 67):

As it was mentioned `@PropertySource` doesn't load yaml file. As a workaround load the file on your own and add loaded properties to `Environment`.

Implemement `ApplicationContextInitializer`:

```
public class YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
  @Override
  public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    try {
        Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource("classpath:file.yml");
        YamlPropertySourceLoader sourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
        PropertySource<?> yamlTestProperties = sourceLoader.load("yamlTestProperties", resource, null);
        applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(yamlTestProperties);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Add your initializer to your test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class, initializers = YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class SimpleTest {
  @Test
  public test(){
    // test your properties
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually this should be the best answer, thanks it worked !

Comment: Mateusz, I have posted answer with `YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer` class where YAML location is defined per test case. If you think it is interesting, feel free to merge it into your answer and I will delete mine. Just let me know in a comment bellow my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is the best answer

Answer (score 53):

`@PropertySource` can be configured by `factory` argument. So you can do something like:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-test.yml", factory = YamlPropertyLoaderFactory.class)
```

Where `YamlPropertyLoaderFactory` is your custom property loader:

```
public class YamlPropertyLoaderFactory extends DefaultPropertySourceFactory {
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        if (resource == null){
            return super.createPropertySource(name, resource);
        }

        return new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(resource.getResource().getFilename(), resource.getResource(), null);
    }
}
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882447/4527110

Comment: This underlying yaml parse throws an `IllegalStateException` when the file doesn't exist instead of the proper `FileNotFoundException` - so in order to make this work with `@PropertySource(..., ignoreResourceNotFound = true)`, you'll need catch and handle this case:  

`try {
  return new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(resource.getResource().getFilename(), resource.getResource(), null);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  throw (IOException) e.getCause();
}`

Comment: If you need to get properties for a specific profile, the third parameter in YamlPropertySourceLoader.load() is the profile name. YamlPropertySourceLoader.load() has changed to return a list rather than a single propertysource. Here's more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697551/10668441

Comment: This is cleanest approach so far.

Comment: for me, it required a little modification in return as follows:
`CompositePropertySource propertySource = new CompositePropertySource(name); new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(resource.getResource().getFilename(), resource.getResource()).stream().forEach(propertySource::addPropertySource); return propertySource;`

Answer (score 40):

Another option is to set the `spring.config.location` through `@TestPropertySource`:

```java
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location = classpath:<path-to-your-yml-file>" }
```

Comment: I have parametrized the input by the following line:

`@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.config.location=classpath:application-${test.env}.yml" })`

IMO yours is the best answer out of all.

Comment: Great idea and very minimalistic for tests, thanks a lot! Just to add, one can include multiple configuration files, per: `@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.config.location=classpath:application-config.yml,classpath:test-config.yml,..." })`

Comment: This is the best answer by far ! note that you need to have `@SpringBootTest` annotation

Comment: I don't want to load all the spring configuration just because i need a property from my yml. This is what `@SpringBootTest` does

Comment: This was the best answer for me thank you

Answer (score 31):

`@PropertySource` only supports properties files (it's a limitation from Spring, not Boot itself). Feel free to open a feature request ticket [in JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR).

**UPDATE** Already opened and rejected Jira requests:

- [Add support for YAML files to @PropertySource SPR-13912](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18486)
- [Document that @PropertySource and @TestPropertySource do not support YAML SPR-16563](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21105)

Comment: I'd hoped there was a way to re-use the yaml listener or to manually load the yaml in an Environment which could be passed into the test config.

Comment: I suppose you could write an `ApplicationContextInitializer` and add it to the test configuration (just use a `YamlPropertySourceLoader` to enhance the `Environment`). Personally I'd prefer it if `@PropertySource` would support this behaviour natively.

Comment: is this still the case? does '@PropertySource' not support YAML?

Answer (score 26):

From Spring Boot 1.4, you can use the new `@SpringBootTest` annotation to achieve this more easily (and to simplify your integration test setup in general) by bootstrapping your integration tests using Spring Boot support.

Details on the [Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4).

As far as I can tell, this means you get all the benefits of Spring Boot's [externalized config goodness](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) just like in your production code, including automatically picking up YAML config from the classpath.

By default, this annotation will

> ... first attempt to load `@Configuration` from any inner-classes, and if that fails, it will search for your primary `@SpringBootApplication` class.

but you can specify other configuration classes if required.

For this particular case, you can combine `@SpringBootTest` with `@ActiveProfiles( "test" )` and Spring will pick up your YAML config, provided it follows the normal Boot naming standards (i.e. `application-test.yml`).

```
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
public class SpringBootITest {

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String username;

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    ...

}
```

Note: `SpringRunner.class` is the new name for `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class`

Comment: :) Using @ActiveProfiles is the only option that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The approach to loading the yaml properties, IMHO can be done in two ways:

a. You can put the configuration in a standard location - `application.yml` in the classpath root - typically `src/main/resources` and this yaml property should automatically get loaded by Spring boot with the flattened path name that you have mentioned.

b. The second approach is a little more extensive, basically define a class to hold your properties this way:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(path="classpath:/appprops.yml", name="db")
public class DbProperties {
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;
...
}
```

So essentially this is saying that load the yaml file and populate the DbProperties class based on the root element of "db".

Now to use it in any class you will have to do this:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DbProperties.class)
public class PropertiesUsingService {

    @Autowired private DbProperties dbProperties;

}
```

Either of these approaches should work for you cleanly using Spring-boot.

Comment: Make sure you have snakeyml in your classpath and the above should work.

Comment: These days (although not at the time this question was asked), `snakeyaml` is pulled in as a transitive dependency by `spring-boot-starter`, so there should be no need to add it to your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`, unless you have a deep-rooted urge to use a different version. :)

Comment: It's now `locations`, not `path`, and the `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` is also required.

Answer (score 7):

Since Spring Boot 2.4.0 you can use [ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.html) as follows:

```java
@SpringJUnitConfig(
    classes = { UserAccountPropertiesTest.TestConfig.class },
    initializers = { ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class }
)
class UserAccountPropertiesTest {

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(UserAccountProperties.class)
    static class TestConfig { }

    @Autowired
    UserAccountProperties userAccountProperties;

    @Test
    void getAccessTokenExpireIn() {
       assertThat(userAccountProperties.getAccessTokenExpireIn()).isEqualTo(120);
    }

    @Test
    void getRefreshTokenExpireIn() {
        assertThat(userAccountProperties.getRefreshTokenExpireIn()).isEqualTo(604800);
    }
}
```

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing-configurationproperties#YAML-binding

Comment: Note that the configuration *must* stay in the `application.yml` file

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround by using `@ActiveProfiles("test")` and adding an application-test.yml file to src/test/resources.

It ended up looking like this:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

}
```

The file application-test.yml just contains the properties that I want to override from application.yml (which can be found in src/main/resources).

Comment: This is what I was trying to use as well. For some reason it doesn't work (Spring Boot 1.3.3) when I use `@Value("${my.property}")` but it works fine if I use `environment.getProperty("my.property")`.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to read some properties into my code and this works with spring-boot 1.3.0.RELEASE

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

// access a properties.yml file like properties
@Bean
public PropertySource properties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("properties.yml"));
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
    // properties need to be processed by beanfactory to be accessible after
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.getAppliedPropertySources().get(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.LOCAL_PROPERTIES_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all of the listed questions, but all of them not work for my task: using specific yaml file for some unit test.
In my case, it works like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.config.location=file:../path/to/specific/config/application.yml"})
public class SomeTest {


    @Value("${my.property.value:#{null}}")
    private String value;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("value = " + value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh for the love of God! Why can't things be simple? I wasted so much time on trying to figure out why the `@TestPropertySource` was not properly loading the yaml values. This seems to be the only way it actually works as expected. I wonder why the TestPropertySource doesn't work, considering Spring is pushing to migrate to yaml files.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an improved version of `YamlPropertyLoaderFactory` which supports the new `PropertySource.ignoreResourceNotFound`, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392715/13705197):

Java:

```java
public final class YamlPropertyLoaderFactory extends DefaultPropertySourceFactory {
    private final YamlPropertySourceLoader yamlPropertySourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();

    @NotNull
    public PropertySource createPropertySource(
            @Nullable String name,
            @NotNull EncodedResource resource
    ) {
        try {
            String parsedName;
            if (name != null && !name.equals(""))
                parsedName = name;
            else parsedName = resource.getResource().getFilename();
            return yamlPropertySourceLoader.load(parsedName, resource.getResource()).get(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Exception possibleFileNotFoundException = ExceptionUtils.throwableOfType(e, FileNotFoundException.class);
            throw possibleFileNotFoundException != null ? possibleFileNotFoundException : e;
        }
    }
}

// Usage
@PropertySource(
   value = {"file:./my-optional-config.yml"},
   factory = YamlPropertyLoaderFactory.class,
   ignoreResourceNotFound = true
)
```

Kotlin:

```
class YamlPropertyLoaderFactory : DefaultPropertySourceFactory() {
    private val yamlPropertySourceLoader = YamlPropertySourceLoader()

    override fun createPropertySource(
        name: String?,
        resource: EncodedResource
    ): PropertySource<*> = try {
        (
            yamlPropertySourceLoader.load(
                if (name != null && name.isNotBlank()) name else resource.resource.filename,
                resource.resource
            )
            )[0]
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw ExceptionUtils.throwableOfType(e, FileNotFoundException::class.java) ?: e
    }
}

// Usage
@PropertySource(
    value = ["file:/my-optional-config.yml"],
    factory = YamlPropertyLoaderFactory::class,
    ignoreResourceNotFound = true
)
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because you have not configure snakeyml. 
spring boot come with @EnableAutoConfiguration feature.
there is snakeyml config too when u call this annotation..

this is my way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppContextTest {
}
```

here is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(
        classes = {
                AppContextTest.class,
                JaxbConfiguration.class,
        }
)

public class JaxbTest {
//tests are ommited
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [YamlPropertiesFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/YamlPropertiesFactoryBean.html) from spring-beans

```
@PropertySource(value = "my-config.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

impl

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), factory.getObject());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading custom yml file with multiple profile config in Spring Boot.

1) Add the property bean with SpringBootApplication start up as follows

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.as.*"})
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesStage() {
        return properties("dev");
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("stage")
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesDev() {
        return properties("stage");
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("default")
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesDefault() {
        return properties("default");

    }
   /**
    * Update custom specific yml file with profile configuration.
    * @param profile
    * @return
    */
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(String profile) {
       PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfig = null;
       YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml  = null;

       propertyConfig  = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
       yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
       yaml.setDocumentMatchers(new SpringProfileDocumentMatcher(profile));// load profile filter.
       yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("env_config/test-service-config.yml"));
       propertyConfig.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
       return propertyConfig;
    }
}
```

2) Config the Java pojo object as follows

```
@Component
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test-service")
public class TestConfig {

    @JsonProperty("id") 
    private  String id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

}
```

3) Create  the custom yml (and place it under resource path as follows,
YML File name : test-service-config.yml

Eg Config in the yml file.

```
test-service: 
    id: default_id
    name: Default application config
---
spring:
  profiles: dev

test-service: 
  id: dev_id
  name: dev application config

--- 
spring:
  profiles: stage

test-service: 
  id: stage_id
  name: stage application config
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing [Mateusz Balbus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37349492/4607349).

Modified `YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer` class where YAML location is defined per test class. It does not work per test, unfortunately.

```
public abstract class YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer
  implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

  /***
   * Return location of a YAML file, e.g.: classpath:file.yml
   *
   * @return YAML file location
   */
  protected abstract String getResourceLocation();

  @Override
  public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    try {
        Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource(getResourceLocation());
        YamlPropertySourceLoader sourceLoader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
        PropertySource<?> yamlTestProperties = sourceLoader.load("yamlTestProperties", resource, null);
        applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(yamlTestProperties);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

Create subclass of `YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer` with defined  `getResourceLocation()` method and add this subclass into `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` annotation.

This way it is easiest to make the test class itself.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class, initializers = SimpleTest.class)
public class SimpleTest extends YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer {

  @Override
  protected String getResourceLocation() {
    return "classpath:test_specific.yml";
  }

  @Test
  public test(){
    // test your properties
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.yingzhuo</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-stater-env</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Welcome to use my library. Now ***yaml***, ***toml***, ***hocon*** is supported.

Source: [github.com](https://github.com/yingzhuo/spring-boot-stater-env)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the original question, but an alternative solution for a need to have a different configuration in a test...

Instead of `@PropertySource` you can use `-Dspring.config.additional-location=classpath:application-tests.yml`.

Be aware, that suffix `tests` does not mean profile...

In that one YAML file one can specify multiple profiles, that can kind of inherit from each other, read more here - [Property resolving for multiple Spring profiles (yaml configuration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60333056/property-resolving-for-multiple-spring-profiles-yaml-configuration)

Then, you can specify in your test, that active profiles (using `@ActiveProfiles("profile1,profile2")`) are `profile1,profile2` where `profile2` will simply override (some, one does not need to override all) properties from `profile1`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

project demo url: https://github.com/Forest10/spring-boot-family/tree/spring-boot-with-yml

I run this answer in my prod env!!! so if you against this ans. please test first!!!

There is no need to add like YamlPropertyLoaderFactory or YamlFileApplicationContextInitializer. You should convert your idea

Follow these steps:

Just add applicationContext.xml like

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
```

to your ApplicationMainClass.

and your applicationContext.xml should write like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  default-autowire="byName"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.yml"/>
</beans>
```

This can help scan your application-test.yml

```
db:
   url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@pathToMyDb
   username: someUser
   password: fakePassword
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392715/5235756

Just for convenience, here is a kotlin version of the java code:

```kotlin
@PropertySource(value = ["classpath:application-test.yml"], factory = YamlPropertyLoaderFactory::class)
```

YamlPropertyLoaderFactory:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource
import org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory
import org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource

class YamlPropertyLoaderFactory : DefaultPropertySourceFactory() {
    @Throws(IllegalStateException::class)
    override fun createPropertySource(name: String?, resource: EncodedResource): PropertySource<*> {
        return YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(resource.resource.filename, resource.resource).first()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use tool to convert from yaml to properties format. Google it there are plenty.
I've been using : https://mageddo.com/tools/yaml-converter

Note : Be careful not to post sensitive data on such online tools

Comment: So your answer is to not do the thing that was asked by the OP? And even then, you just tell them to google it?

Comment: I came to this thread cause i was trying to solve the same issue and saw all the implementations being suggested. I suggested it cause it took just < 2 minutes for me to think about KISS and posted the answer here. I would rather spend time on writing tests and solve business problems than battling my own "requirement creation".OP wants to write tests and not having to worry about configuration and data format issues. I generally don't promote tools hence did not post it here. Lot of them have security issues as they store data.