# Cannot load config from custom yml file in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, properties-file

I am loading the custom configuration from application.yml in my spring boot service.

I have annotated by bean class as below,

```
    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties("app")
    public class ContinentConfig {

    private Map<String, List<Country>> continents = new HashMap<String, List<Country>>();

          //get/set/tostring methods
  }
```

My custom class Country includes 2 fields,

```
public class Country {

    String name;
    String capital;

    //get/set/tostring methods
}
```

In application.yml I have as below,

```
app:
  continents: 
    Europe: 
      - name: France
        capital: Paris
    Asia: 
      - name: China
        capital: Beijing
```

With the above setup, I am able to load the config from **application.yml**.

I now want to extract the config to a separate **continentconfig.yml** in the same **src/main/resources** folder. So, I moved the custom config to continentconfig.yml leaving other properties like **server.port** in application.yml.

The **continentconfig.yml** has the same content as I had earlier in application.yml.

I also added the below annotations to the ContinentConfig Class,

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value="classpath:continentconfig.yml")
public class ContinentConfig {

}
```

After this change, I see the config is not getting loaded from **continentconfig.yml** to **ContinentConfig** bean.

Can someone please help in resolving the issue.

Comment: just take a look at this answer here:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml/54247009#54247009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml/54247009#54247009) .it`s easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer you can't do that and you should use the property file.

> 24.6.4 YAML shortcomings
>
> YAML files can’t be loaded via the @PropertySource annotation. So in
>   the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a
>   properties file.

You can create your initializer and use the `YamlPropertySourceLoader`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But, is there another way to externalize the custom config in it own yml file , perhaps using it as a profile specific yml file.

Comment: You can have a base configuration in `application.yml` and you can override it for required profiles `application-dev.yml` etc. There is another workaround by using `YamlPropertySourceLoader`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml

Answer (score 0):

I believe by externalizing you mean using a property file to load the configuration from a file configured in github/or other such hosting repos?  You could very well do that by using bootstrap.yml. This loads all the configurations from an external file and also allows the provision to override them using the local application.properties/application.yml

spring:
  application:
    name: 
  cloud :
    config :
      uri :

Also make sure that you have spring cloud in your pom to resolve this just in case

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Just incase if your local yml property files are not loaded in your classpath, then add the following

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                    <include>**/*.jks</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

Note: It is preferred to have the YamlPropertySourceLoader to load your config file to your classpath and on top of that you could use the above config