# Spring boot tests - Can't find test properties

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project and it works great. I now want to write tests for my application and I am running into some configuration headaches.

Spring boot created a test class for me called ApplicationTests. It's real simple and it looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DuurzaamApplicationTests {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }    
}
```

Now when I start the tests I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'company.upload' in value "${company.upload}"
```

I have a properties.yml file in the src/test/resources directory and for some reason it isn't loaded. I have tried all different kind of annotations from examples on the Internet and yet none of them work.

How can I tell spring boot tests to use an application.yml file to load the properties from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @PropertySource using YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can use `@TestPropertySource` or `@PropertySource` to load the properties file.

Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:properties.yml")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DuurzaamApplicationTests {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }    
}
```

Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html

Comment: Doesn't work. I still get "Could not resolve placeholder 'company.upload' in value "${company.upload}". I have the application.yml located in the src/test/resources directory.

Comment: can you share the project in gist or git ?

Comment: or define the value in application-test.yml under src/main/resources and by default springboot includes test profile while running test

Comment: The last tip helped solve the property value unfornately then the spring datasource doesn't get override. application-test.yml resolves the property value however the spring datasource is still being used instead of the supplied h2 database in application-test.yml.

I have tried using both application files and also using @TestPropertySource and indiacting both application files and then the Value is unresolved again. Something very wierd with spring going on I guess.

Comment: Use @ActiveProfiles("test") and try

Comment: That work's perfectly. The datasource is overriden and my properties are loaded.

Comment: See my answer below. `.yml` is not supported, only `.properties` and `.xml` are.

Answer (score 14):

To my surprise, when you load properties files in Spring Boot Test, `.yml` is not supported. It's noted in the documentation, although implicitly.

From the link above:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html

> Supported File Formats
>
> Both traditional and XML-based properties file formats are supported — for example, "classpath:/com/example/test.properties" or "file:/path/to/file.xml".

`.yml` is not mentioned.

And, after changing my `.yml` to `.properties` and rewrite the values in `xx.xx.xx=value` form, the key-values pairs can be read correctly.

So strange.

EDIT:

Now I find a ticket address this issue; seems a long-known bug in Spring.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18486

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite your `.yml` you can also use the following for tests: 

`@SpringBootTest(
    properties = { "my.property=test" }`

Note that the format for the properties has to be the one of `.properties` files, i.e. using `=` as separator.
)`

Answer (score 4):

`@PropertySource` and `@TestPropertySource` do not work with YAML. See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10772#issuecomment-339581902).

I also tested it myself. Try creating 2 files - *.yml and *.properties and see it for yourself.

To make `*.yml` work most people use `@SpringBootTest`, but if it's not what you want and you would like to use `@ContextConfiguration` instead, you are in for a bit of surprise.

Answer (score 0):

For me the above solutions did not work and any environment variables were still overriding the test properties defined in @TestPropertySource even though https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html indicates that this source should have higher precedence than environment variables.  The only solution that worked for me was to manually define a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in a test configuration class and set it with highest precedence.

This was with Spring Boot 1.5.15.RELEASE

```
@Configuration
@TestPropertySource(properties = "/application-test.properties")
@Slf4j
public class IntegrationTestConfiguration {

@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc
          = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[]
          { new ClassPathResource( "/application-test.properties" ) };
    ppc.setLocations( resources );
    ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
    ppc.setOrder( Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE );

    return ppc;
}

/// ....

@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
@Import( IntegrationTestConfiguration.class )
@SpringBootTest( webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT )
public class MyTest {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, my problem was a `application.properties` in `src\test\resources` which was missing the new properties

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your `application-test.properties` file can't be found because it is in a subfolder off the class path.

for example this may not be found, because the file is actually not directly in the class path.

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
```

but this will be found if the file is in the `config` folder off of a path in the class path

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:config/application-test.properties")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use annotation of @ActiveProfiles("test") that support application-test.yml or application-test.properties