# Spring profile is ignored when reading properties from application.yml

Tags: java, spring

I have this code that scans Spring context:

```
public void scan() {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

    context.register(SomeConfig.class);
    context.refresh();
}
```

I need properties to be read from `application.yml` file, so in `SomeConfig` class, I have this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yml", factory = YamlPropertyLoaderFactory.class)
public class SomeConfig {
  //some beans
}
```

(I have copied YamlPropertyLoaderFactory class from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392715/3026283))

`application.yml` is a typical Spring Boot file with some properties by profile, and a default profile:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: p1

---

spring:
   profiles: p1

file: file1.txt

---

spring:
   profiles: p2

file: file2.txt
```

In some bean, I'm reading `file` property using `@Value`.

When I run my application, I'm passing `-Dspring.profiles.active=p1` variable, but I'm getting an error:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'file' in value "${file}"

(It should work even if I don't pass any profile since application.yml has default profile set to p1)

If I remove all profiles config from `application.yml`, it works fine:

```
file: file1.txt
```

So, it means that context scan is not reading the profile variable.

Also, if I set active profile "programatically", it doesn't resolve the properties either:

```
context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("p1");
```

Comment: Have you checked in the logs that the desired profile was really activated?

Comment: @J-Alex yes, and it is. But it doesn't resolve the variables.

Comment: @Héctor What Spring version do you have? And are you using spring boot or not?

Comment: do you use maven/gradle to build ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `YamlPropertyLoaderFactory` you refer to has the following code:

```
public class YamlPropertyLoaderFactory extends DefaultPropertySourceFactory {
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        if (resource == null){
            return super.createPropertySource(name, resource);
        }

        return new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(resource.getResource().getFilename(), resource.getResource(), null);
    }
}
```

The third parameter to the `YamlPropertySourceLoader.load()` method is actually the profile name that you want the properties for. As this example passes in null it just returns the  set of properties from the yml file not for a specific profile.

i.e.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: p1

---
```

I don't think it's easy to pick up the active profile name in the `YamlPropertyLoaderFactory`, although you could try something like...

```
public class YamlPropertyLoaderFactory extends DefaultPropertySourceFactory {
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        if (resource == null){
            return super.createPropertySource(name, resource);
        }

        String activeProfile = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
        return new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(resource.getResource().getFilename(), resource.getResource(), activeProfile);
    }
}
```

Or as you have the active profile name in the yml file, you could call `YamlPropertySourceLoader().load` with null to get the spring.profiles.active property then call it again to load the actual part of the yml file you want.

```
public class YamlPropertyLoaderFactory extends DefaultPropertySourceFactory {
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        if (resource == null){
            return super.createPropertySource(name, resource);
        }
        PropertySource<?> source = new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(resource.getResource().getFilename(), resource.getResource(), null);
        String activeProfile = source.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
        return new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(resource.getResource().getFilename(), resource.getResource(), activeProfile);
    }
}
```

`YamlPropertySourceLoader` was changed back in feb 2018 ([YamlPropertySourceLoader blame view in Git repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blame/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/env/YamlPropertySourceLoader.java)). It now returns a list of propertySource and does not have the third parameter on the load method.

Provided you have the spring.profiles.active property in the yml file you'd be able to do the following with the newer version of `YamlPropertySourceLoader`

```
public class YamlPropertyLoaderFactory extends DefaultPropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        if (resource == null){
            return super.createPropertySource(name, resource);
        }
        List<PropertySource<?>> sources = new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(resource.getResource().getFilename(), resource.getResource());
        for (PropertySource<?> checkSource : sources) {
            if (checkSource.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active")) {
                String activeProfile = (String) checkSource.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
                for (PropertySource<?> source : sources) {
                    if (activeProfile.trim().equals(source.getProperty("spring.profiles"))) {
                        return source; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return sources.get(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved my issue and this helped me a lot to understand how properties sources work in Spring,

Comment: If the `resource` parameter is null, this will throw a `NullPointerException` anyway. So, is the `if (resource == null) {...}` guard really useful?

Comment: @Kruschenstein as you say, it doesn't achieve anything useful. The OP posted a link to the source they had the problem with. The problem was about loading properties from yaml for a specific profile. I just focused on the problem when I answered.

Comment: @pcoates Yes I understand! I prefere notify anyway to complete the answer (your code truly helped me ^^)

Comment: doesn't work if there is no 'spring.profiles.active' in yml. Is there some idea to pick up the active profile from the spring environment?

Comment: ```System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")``` is workaround in this stage.

Answer (score 0):

@pcoates I tried with newer version of YamlPropertySourceLoader still failing to load profile.

Always failing in condition below with source returned with 2 elements without source "spring.profiles.active",

`if (checkSource.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active"))`

Below is my yaml and configuration for yaml property loader

````
  profiles: dev
  excelPath :  /data/excel
  excecutionPath: http://localhost:8080/server/execute
  memberIP: localhost
  profilerPortNum: 3031

--- 

spring:
  profiles: uat
  excelPath :  /data/uat/excel
  excecutionPath: http://localhost:8080/server/execute
  memberIP: localhost
  profilerPortNum: 3032```

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yml", factory = YamlPropertyLoaderFactory.class)
public class ReadYamlProperties {
}
````

Comment: Resolved by using @Component
@ConfigurationProperties("spring")                                                                      
public String getExcelPath() {
  return excelPath;
 }

 public void setExcelPath(String excelPath) {
  this.excelPath = excelPath;
 }

Answer (score -1):

To set a property only for a specific profile, the correct indentation is:

```
spring:
   profiles: p1
   file: file1.txt
```

In the above case, you can access `file1.txt` with `${spring.file}` EL.

Comment: `file` is a custom property, not relating either to `spring` or to `spring.profiles`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko The OP said:  "typical Spring Boot file with some properties by profile" so the file property is bound to the p1 and p2 respectively - at least this is what I understand. Otherwise, why `file` would appear two times?

Comment: You should not add custom properties to spring prefix