# Spring boot : Properties values not getting set in Test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

Below is my project structure

```
SomeProject
    -src/main/java
    -src/main/resources
    -src/test/java
    -src/test/resources
        application-test.yml
```

Below are the contents of my properties file

### application-test.yml

```
pre:
    someUrl: http://someurl
```

Below are the contents of the configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pre")
public class SomeConfiguration {

    private String someUrl;

    public String getsomeUrl() {
        return someUrl;
    }

    public void setsomeUrl(String someUrl) {
        this.someUrl = someUrl;
    }
}
```

Below is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=SomeConfiguration.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application-test.yml"})
public class SomeServiceTest {

    SomeObject someObject;

    @Autowired
    private SomeConfiguration someConfiguration; 

    @Test
    public void somMethodTest() {
        someObject = new SomeObject ();
        someObject.setsomeUrl(someConfiguration.getsomeUrl());

    }
}
```

The problem is I am getting null when I am trying to set **someURL** in **someObject**. I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow and accepted answers as well, but I am still getting null.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `@ConfigurationProperties` documentation:

> Getters and setters are usually mandatory, since binding is through
>   standard Java Beans property descriptors.

A setter for `private String sameUrl` is **setSameUrl** and NOT **setsameUrl**.

So spring may read that from properties file but it cannot inject that through the setter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately yml files are not supported with @TestPropertySource or @PropertySource.

I don't think the documentation for @TestPropertySource is clear on this fact, but the following [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16563) has been closed. One of the comments says...

> the locations attribute in @TestPropertySource already provides the following documentation:
>
> Supported File Formats
>
> Both traditional and XML-based properties file formats are supported — for example, "classpath:/com/example/test.properties" or "file:/path/to/file.xml".

The following from the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings) spells it out for @PropertySource:

> 24.7.4 YAML Shortcomings
>
> YAML files cannot be loaded by using the @PropertySource annotation.
>   So, in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use
>   a properties file.

You can get @PropertySource to load yaml if you [create a suitable factory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697551/10668441), not sure if you can do it with @TestPropertySource.