# Spring Boot: custom properties configuration and tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0 with default `application.yml` properties file. I would like to split it to separate property files because it becomes huge.
Also I would like to write tests to check properties correctness: values that will present on production application context (not the test one).

Here is my property file: **src/main/resources/config/custom.yml**

```
my-property:
  value: 'test'
```

Property class:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-property")
@PropertySource("classpath:config/custom.yml")
public class MyProperty {

  private String value;
}
```

Test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyProperty.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MyPropertyTest {

  @Autowired
  private MyProperty property;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    assertEquals("test", property.getValue());
  }

}
```

But test fails with error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :test
Actual   :null
```

Also I see that property value is `null` when running the application by printing it in `ApplicationRunner`.
When I used `application.yml` for all properties it were well with the same configuration.

How to put correct configuration for properties and tests for make it work?
Link to [Github repo](https://github.com/bullet-tooth/spring-custom-properties)

Comment: Have you tries using `@TestPropertySource` annotation for providing the location of your configuration files?

Comment: Plus cases like this are easier to debug if you could create a very simple minimal application and provide a link to it from github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @PropertySource using YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml)

Comment: @Prashant here is: https://github.com/bullet-tooth/spring-custom-properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finely I found the right way for having custom yaml properties in my app.

The issue is that Spring doesn't support yaml files as `@PropertySource` ([link to issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13912)). And here is a workaround how to deal with that described in [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context).
So, to be able to load properties from yaml files you need:
* To implement `EnvironmentPostProcessor`
* To register it in `spring.factories`

Please visit this [github repo](https://github.com/bullet-tooth/spring-custom-properties) for complete example.

Also, thanks a lot for your support, guys!

Answer (score 2):

`@TestPropertySource` can solve your problem.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyProperty.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class MyPropertyTest {

@Autowired
private MyProperty property;

@Test
public void test() {
   assertEquals("test", property.getValue());
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: As mentioned by OP in the accepted answer, `@TestPropertySource` currently doesn't work with yml files.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late to the party, but this might also help. The solution provided as answer is the best approach so far, but here is an alternative that I used

Make use of profiles and modify the PropertySoucesPlaceHolderConfiguration bean to do load the necessary property files based on the profiles. It loads the application.properties as the default one but the other propertyfiles -oauth_DEV and oauth_QA are loaded based on the profiles set

```
@Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurerconfigurer() {

        System.out.println("Inside Placeholder bean");
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer cfg = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ClassPathResource cls1=  new ClassPathResource("application.properties");
         ClassPathResource cls2 = null;

        Map<String, Object> propMap = ((ConfigurableEnvironment) ctx.getEnvironment()).getSystemProperties();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entrySet: propMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Map.Key:"+entrySet.getKey()+"  Map.valiue:"+entrySet.getValue());
        }

        List<String> profiles=  Arrays.asList(ctx.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles());
        if(profiles == null || profiles.isEmpty()) {
            if(!propMap.containsKey("spring.profiles.active")) {
                cls2 = new ClassPathResource("oauth-default.properties");
            } else {
                cls2 = new ClassPathResource("oauth-"+propMap.get("spring.profiles.active")+".properties");
            }
        }else {
            for(String profile:profiles) {
                if(profile.equalsIgnoreCase("DEV")) {
                    cls2 =  new ClassPathResource("oauth-DEV.properties");
                }else if(profile.equalsIgnoreCase("QA")) {
                    cls2 =  new ClassPathResource("oauth-QA.properties");
                }else if (profile.equalsIgnoreCase("UAT")) {
                    cls2 =  new ClassPathResource("oauth-UAT.properties");
                }else if(profile.equalsIgnoreCase("PROD")){
                    cls2 =  new ClassPathResource("oauth-PROD.properties");
                }else {
                    cls2 = new ClassPathResource("oauth-default.properties");
                }
            }
        }

        cfg.setLocations(cls1,cls2);
        //cfg.setPlaceholderPrefix("#{");
        return cfg;
    }
```

Then create another bean that reads the properties based on the prefix - "security.oauth2.client"

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="security.oauth2.client")
public class OauthSecurityConfigurationDto {

    private String clientId;
    private String clientSecret;
    private String scope;
    private String accessTokenUri;
    private String userAuthorizationUri;
    private String grantType;
    private String resourceIds;
    private String registeredRedirectUri;
    private String preEstablishedRedirectUri;
    private String useCurrentUri;
    private String userInfoUri;
    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }
    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }
    public String getClientSecret() {
        return clientSecret;
    }
    public void setClientSecret(String clientSecret) {
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }
    public String getScope() {
        return scope;
    }
    public void setScope(String scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }
    public String getAccessTokenUri() {
        return accessTokenUri;
    }
    public void setAccessTokenUri(String accessTokenUri) {
        this.accessTokenUri = accessTokenUri;
    }
    public String getUserAuthorizationUri() {
        return userAuthorizationUri;
    }
    public void setUserAuthorizationUri(String userAuthorizationUri) {
        this.userAuthorizationUri = userAuthorizationUri;
    }
    public String getGrantType() {
        return grantType;
    }
    public void setGrantType(String grantType) {
        this.grantType = grantType;
    }
    public String getResourceIds() {
        return resourceIds;
    }
    public void setResourceIds(String resourceIds) {
        this.resourceIds = resourceIds;
    }
    public String getRegisteredRedirectUri() {
        return registeredRedirectUri;
    }
    public void setRegisteredRedirectUri(String registeredRedirectUri) {
        this.registeredRedirectUri = registeredRedirectUri;
    }
    public String getPreEstablishedRedirectUri() {
        return preEstablishedRedirectUri;
    }
    public void setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(String preEstablishedRedirectUri) {
        this.preEstablishedRedirectUri = preEstablishedRedirectUri;
    }
    public String getUseCurrentUri() {
        return useCurrentUri;
    }
    public void setUseCurrentUri(String useCurrentUri) {
        this.useCurrentUri = useCurrentUri;
    }
    public String getUserInfoUri() {
        return userInfoUri;
    }
    public void setUserInfoUri(String userInfoUri) {
        this.userInfoUri = userInfoUri;
    }


}
```

Remember the setters are important because the `ConfigurationProperties` load the values into the properties of the class only when getters and setters are defined

Now we can autowire the dependency wherever needed and use the property.

Answer (score 0):

If This is your exact code that means you are reading your property from a wrong property file.

replace your property resource to this line.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config/services.yml")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I missed that and fixed in my question. But it doesn't help :(.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties