# Springboot failed to map properties file to variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

i want to map values between a yaml file with a `Map<String, List<String>>` in springboot

`country.yml` file:

```
entries:
  map:
     MY:
      - en
      - zh
```

`SampleConfig` file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties("entries")
public class SampleConfig {

    private Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Bean
    public void bean1(){
        System.err.println("map has size: "+map.size());
    }
}
```

But the `map.size()` is always 0, not sure what i do wrong.

Comment: I think you need getter/setter for this to work..

Comment: why this `country.yml` is not `application.yml`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems

1) By default spring will look for `application.yml` or `application.properties` in default locations

To solve the above problem you can use `application.yml` instead of `country.yml`

2) You can use `@PropertySource` to load any external properties file but `yml` is not supported with this annotation

[24.7.4 YAML Shortcomings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings) you cannot use `@PropertySource` with `yml` file

> **YAML files cannot be loaded by using the @PropertySource annotation.** So, in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a properties file.

[How to read yml file using Spring @PropertySource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml)

Comment: i tried the `@PropertySource` plus with setters and getters as others suggested, it is still not working

Comment: `@PropertySource` explicitly does not support YAML yet.

Comment: updated my answer, it is taking time to gather all information @hades

Answer (score 2):

this will work and print out `CountryData : {MY=[en, zh]}`

**but surely read the answer from Deadpool.**

the *hack* is here to override the default configuration name 'application' by 'country'

in the example, I have done it by setting it via a System property, but starting your application via 
`java -jar mycountryapp.jar --spring.config.name=country` should work perfectly

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    static {
      System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "country");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

@Service
class CountryService {
  private final CountryData countryData;
    public CountryService(CountryData countryData) {
        this.countryData = countryData;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void showCountryDataOnStartup() {
      System.err.println("CountryData : " + countryData.getMap());
    }

}

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "entries")
class CountryData {

    Map<String, List<String>> map;

    public Map<String, List<String>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks! I found another way that uses `PropertySourceFactor` to read from the yaml file as suggested in this link https://mdeinum.github.io/2018-07-04-PropertySource-with-yaml-files/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your application is picking the configuration from `country.yml` (I would check that as well) - You need getters and setters to get it to work. just add:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties("entries")
public class SampleConfig {

    private Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, List<String>> getMap(){
        return map;
    }
    public void setMap(Map<String, List<String>> map){
        this.map=map;
    }

}
```

Comment: i actually added `@PropertySource("classpath:country.yml")` also, but the map size is still 0