# Configuring H2 database via Yaml - Spring Boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, yaml, h2

I have a spring boot app, and I want to configure my H2 database with Yaml. It crashes whenever I would run this.

**My app.yml file:**

```
spring:
  database: h2
  console: true
  path: /h2

datasource:
  platform: h2
  url: jdbc:h2://localhost:8080/h2
  username: sa
  password: 1234
  driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- H2 Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

....
</dependencies>
```

I do not know how to use yaml very well, and I need help to see if my yaml can be fixed to incorporate H2 database.

I am trying to do this: https://dzone.com/articles/integrate-h2-database-in-your-spring-boot-applicat

But with `app.yml` instead of `app.properties`.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Here is my crash,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration$ServletSessionConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b764bce]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:404) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:389) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:447) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1751) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:738) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:679) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:647) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:479) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1226) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:905) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:891) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:877) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:826) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
at pw.restMaker.restMaker.RestMakerApplication.main(RestMakerApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/authentication/RememberMeServices
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1007) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3139) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2266) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.RememberMeServices
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496) ~[na:na]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What is the issue here ?

Comment: I cannot use the yaml, it is incorrect and therefore it gives me errors. EDIT: thanks for telling me!

Comment: Can you provide the bit error details ?

Comment: error has nothing to do with your datasource. There is something wrong with your security configuration

Comment: Hmm, strange. I never added security to my app as I didn't have use for it. But if it fixes this error then I can download it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given :

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

Something like this should work :

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:~/test
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

The file should be placed in `src/main/resources` directory and named `application.yml`.

Comment: This gave me an IllegalStateException, Failed to introspect Class. Should I post the error code into my answer?

Comment: you could leave out property  ```driverClassName```, spring can determine driver class from url

Comment: @Compilerv2 there is probably a problem with naming your yml file ```app.yml```  [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399658/springboot-failed-to-map-properties-file-to-variable/56400252#56400252). Try to use ```application.yml```

Comment: I shortened the name to app.yml for convenience, but actually, it is application.yml

Comment: I never downloaded spring security from spring initializer, and it is not in my classpath. I don't need it, as I am not working with it, but if it fixes this error then sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
spring:
  application:
        name: department-service
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:department-service
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

The **application.yml** configuration you can make it like below.

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:~/test
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```