# Cannot correctly load application.yaml from SpringBoot/JUnit

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I am a newbie with SpringBoot and I am trying to develop a first application.

My application has a configuration that is provided in an `application.yaml`. Currently, it successfully reads its configuration at startup.

However, if I embed my application in a Springboot/JUnit test, the `application.yaml` is not correctly exploited.

> My impression is that, using Springboot/JUnit, `application.yaml` is
>   read as if it was an `application.properties`: it only accepts
>   parameters that are provided on a single line (e.g. `thread-pool: 10`)
>   but not on a multi-line
>
> ```
> wordpress:
>   themes:
>     default-folder: /wp-content/themes/mkyong
> ```

---

I reproduced the same issue from a project I found in github: https://github.com/mkyong/spring-boot.git, in the directory `yaml-simple`

the application successfully reads its configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private WordpressProperties wpProperties;

    @Autowired
    private GlobalProperties globalProperties;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println(globalProperties);
        System.out.println(wpProperties);
    }
}
```

But if I create the following JUnit test in the directory
`src/test/java/com/mkyong`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.yml")
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private WordpressProperties wpProperties;

    @Autowired
    private GlobalProperties globalProperties;


    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(globalProperties.getThreadPool() == 10); /// OK
        Assert.assertEquals("/wp-content/themes/mkyong", wpProperties.getThemes().getDefaultFolder()); // KO
    }

    @SpringBootApplication
    static class TestConfiguration {
    }

}
```

while running it, the configuration is only partially read!!!

*(please note that my problem does not appear using `application.properties` but I prefer yaml against properties)*

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml

Answer (score 2):

Thanks the answer of user7294900, I found that adding the annotation `@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)` to my test class solved the problem:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.yml")
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private WordpressProperties wpProperties;

    @Autowired
    private GlobalProperties globalProperties;


    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(globalProperties.getThreadPool() == 10);
        Assert.assertEquals("/wp-content/themes/mkyong", wpProperties.getThemes().getDefaultFolder());
    }

    @SpringBootApplication
    static class TestConfiguration {
    }

}
```