# ConfigurationProperties in nested classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot

With following yml

```
app:
  a:
    prop: aaa
  b:
    prop: bbb
```

```java
@Component
public abstract class Common {

    @Value("${prop}")
    private String prop;

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.a")
    @PropertySource("classpath:app.yml")
    @Component
    public static class A extends Common {
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.b")
    @PropertySource("classpath:app.yml")
    @Component
    public static class B extends Common {
    }
}
```

But those two classes has same value, either for `a` or `b`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does it work if you bring A and B to the top level?

Comment: @jannis Nope. Moving those inner classes to outer level didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. Simply. [`yml` doesn't work with `PropertySource`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21276836/330457).

I'm still want to believe I'm wrong.

I changed the `.yml` file to `properties` and tried with this.

```java
@PropertySource("classpath:/vendor.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public abstract class Common {

    @Value("${prop}")
    private String prop;

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.a")
    @Component
    public static class A extends Common {
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.b")
    @Component
    public static class B extends Common {
    }
}
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list for your configuration parameters :

```
app:
  props: 
    - key: a
      value: aaa

    - key: b
      value: bbb
```

And retreive your value with a more complex way in a separate bean :

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class CommonConfiguration {
    List<Prop> props;
    //Getters and setters
    public Prop retreiveSpecificConfiguration(String className) {
        //some kind of logic here
    }

    public static class Prop {
      private String key, value;
      //Getters and setters
    }
}
```

Inject it in your Common class implementation :

```
@Autowired
CommonConfiguration config;
```