# Can't load a test-properties.yaml file with the @TestPropertySource with Spring Boot, JUnit5 and Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, yaml

I have a class that is injected with the `application.yaml` properties located in the `src/main/resources` directory.
I wrote a test that is asserting if those properties are injected as expected.
The test does work fine but it is using the `application.yaml` file from `src/main/resources`.

I want it to use the `test-application.yaml` file from `src/test/resources` to use some bogus values.

I followed many guides and read many questions here on Stackoverflow but could not get any of those approaches to work. Maybe because I mixed up different solution's annotations or whatever.

### Status Quo

I am using the spring versions provided by the spring management system

```
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
```

**Edit:**
Also I use the following relevant dependencies:

```
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
```

The property file `src/main/resources/application.yaml`:

```
controlroom:
  ftpConnections:
    foo-importer:
      host: ftp.stage.company.com
      port: 22
      user: foo-ftp
      password: password
    bar-importer:
      host: ftp.stage.company.com
      port: 22
      user: bar-ftp
      password: password
```

This is the property configuration holder class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "controlroom")
class FtpConnectionsProvider(
) {
    lateinit var ftpConnections: Map<String, Map<String, String>>
}
```

And this is the test class that currently is injecting the properties from `main/resources/application.yaml`:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest
internal class FtpConnectionsProviderTest(
        @Autowired
        val ftpConnectionsProvider: FtpConnectionsProvider
) {
    @Test
    fun `should fill FtpConnectionsProvider with properties from yaml`() {
        assertThat(ftpConnectionsProvider.ftpConnections["foo-importer"]).containsAllEntriesOf(
                mapOf(
                        "host" to "ftp.stage.company.com",
                        "port" to "22",
                        "user" to "foo-ftp",
                        "password" to "password"
                ))
        assertThat(ftpConnectionsProvider.ftpConnections["bar-importer"]).containsAllEntriesOf(
                mapOf(
                        "host" to "ftp.stage.company.com",
                        "port" to "22",
                        "user" to "bar-ftp",
                        "password" to "password"
                ))
    }
}
```

### How to use the test-application.yaml ?

Now I wonder how I can give the test the instruction to only use `src/test/resources/test-application.yaml`.

#### First Try

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test-application.yaml")
internal class FtpConnectionsProviderTest
```

**Result**: Just ignores it and keeps using `src/main/resources/application.yaml`

#### Second Try

People say that `@TestPropertySource` can't read `.yaml` files and therefore I added the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation since this was the suggested fix.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test-application.yaml")
@ContextConfiguration(initializers=[ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer::class])
internal class FtpConnectionsProviderTest
```

**Result**: Just ignores it and keeps using `src/main/kotlin/resources/application.yaml`

*Nothing seems to work. I do not grasp why this is such a big deal and why it is so complicated to find a solution*

Comment: are you sure to have [SnakeYaml](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml) on your classpath?

Comment: @xerx593 Yes. https://imgur.com/a/dANSEdf

Comment: no-no, sorry, the image is no proof: you show me/us a `*.yaml` file ...i/we need: a dependency on `spring-boot[-...]-starter` / `snake-yaml` in your pom.xml/build.gradle.

Comment: @xerx593 please see my edit on status quo regarding the dependencies I use. I want to mention again that the injection of .yaml file does work but I can't refer to the one in the `src/test/kolin/resources` directory

Comment: ..ok, then another "eye-catcher": why is it `src/test/ko[t]lin/resources` ?? it is "no standard" ...if you didn't configure in your pom/gradle (then the yaml file never makes it to "classpath"). I would expect: `src/test/resources/**` or `src/main/resources/**`.

Comment: ..definitly: don't put your yaml-files into "source" folders (src/[main|test]/[java|kotlin]), but all to "resources" folder (language independent: src/[main|test]/resources) (and please check the "output folder" target/[test-]classes for yaml files)

Comment: @xerx593 sorry I was in a haste while typing. Surely I follow the proper convention for resources `src/test/resources`

Comment: thx! :) (1 "side effect" excluded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried placing a `application.yaml` file under `src/test/kotlin/resources`?  That should work without any special config / annotations.

Also, if you want to have / override certain properties within a yaml file called `testfoo`, you can place these props in a `application-testfoo.yaml` in the same directory, and the file will be used if you activate a `testfoo` Spring profile.

Example:

`src/test/kotlin/resources/application.yaml`:

```
controlroom:
  ftpConnections:
    foo-importer:
      host: ftp.stage.company.com
      port: 22
      user: foo-ftp
      password: password
    bar-importer:
      host: ftp.stage.company.com
      port: 22
      user: bar-ftp
      password: password
```

`src/test/kotlin/resources/application-testfoo.yaml`:

```
controlroom:
  ftpConnections:
    foo-importer:
      user: test-foo-ftp
```

If you active the `testfoo` profile, `controlroom.ftpConnections.foo-importer.user` will be overridden.  Is that what you want?

Alternatively, as an even simpler solution if you just want to replace a couple of your production prop values:  Don't create a `src/test/kotlin/resources/application.yaml` at all.  Just create the `src/test/kotlin/resources/application-testfoo.yaml` and it should override the values from `src/main/kotlin/resources/application.yaml` (assuming the `testfoo` profile is active)!  That works in Java with my `applications.properties` anyways - I see no reason why it should work any differently in Kotlin.

Comment: wouldn't this end up in a package called `resources` in `target/test-classes` folder?

Comment: this does work indeed @Joel
The thing is I want to split up different `test-foo-application.yaml` for readability reasons

Comment: Readability of the yaml files?  If so, have you considered using a spring profile named `testfoo` for example and naming the yaml file `application-testfoo.yaml` (under the same test directory)?  If you use that naming convention, Spring should find it.  You can have a application.yaml file and any values in the application-testfoo.yaml file will override them.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot load yaml file using `@TestPropertySource`.

Comment: Completely impossible?
How can I then bring in a `.yaml` properties file for testing purpose

Comment: Easiest is to use standard application.yml file in a test folder (I assume you are uing Maven), instead of different file, use different profile for tests subset, which needs to be configured differently...

Comment: that's quite a good "summary" from today's p.o.v, but still a "never ending story" :) ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/21271468/592355