# How to load different xml file using @PropertySource in Spring

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, annotations, azure-sql-database

I would like to load different query xml files at runtime using configuration file (helm or .property). What I want to achieve is to load 1.xml when I am loading Oracle database and 2.xml when loading Azure SQL.

These databases (Oracle/Azure SQL) are loaded interchangeably, which means I am defining which database is loading in my configuration like this:

```
datasource.project.driverClassName='Oracle' //or 'SQLServerDriver'
datasource.project.url='OracleUrl' // or 'SQLUrl'
```

I want to add flag like `datasource.project.dialect='Oracle'` or something like that so I can indicate which database I am loading.

Once this is done, I want my repository class to load different xml files that contains different sql queries. But I am not sure how I can define this in the @PropertySource annotation. Here is example:

```
@Configuration
@Import(DataSourceConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:event-sql-oracle.xml") //HOW DO I LOAD XML DYNAMICALLY USING THE FLAG?
```

So if flag says 'Oracle', I want to load "classpath:event-sql-oracle.xml" and if it says 'Azure SQL', I want to load "classpath:event-sql-Azure.xml". Is this achieveable?

Comment: Does this help ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml

Comment: I don't think exactly. I found some source and I think what I need to know is how to use placeholder in @PropertySource..

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I just need to use placeholder for `@PropertySource` like this:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:event-sql-${dbtype}.xml")
```

then define `dbtype` in the configuration like .properties or helm.