# Is bootstrap.yml required?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a test class annotated with

```
@SpringBootTest.
@ActiveProfiles("default")
```

There was originally a bootstrap.yml file with the following contents

```
spring:
  application:
    name: [insert name]
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
    vault:
      enabled: false
```

I would like to move the contents of bootstrap.yml into application-default.yml and delete bootstrap.yml, but this causes the tests to fail. Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this annotation:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-default.yml")
```

Just make sure that your application-default.yml is on resource paste.

edit: take a look
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26840503/11329776