# Springboot Unable to Read Yaml config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, yaml

I am trying out a few things about YAML configuration, seems like I am missing something.

Below is my controller class and Yaml file.

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
@PropertySource("file:${user.dir}/config/webappdemo.yml")
public class HomeController {
    
    @Value("${app.message}")
    private String appMessage;

    @GetMapping("/home")
    @ResponseBody
    public String homePage() {
        return this.appMessage;
    }
}
```

webappdemo.yml

```
app:
   message: hello
```

My application failing to start, with the below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.message' in value "${app.message}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
```

From the error message I can feel, because of some reason, It's not able to find that property
If I modify the property file as below, Its working, Please help me identify the issue:

webappdemo.yml

```
app.message=hello
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PropertySource` **doesn't** support `.yml`, you need to use `.properties` file in this case.

> "YAML files **cannot** be loaded by using the `@PropertySource` or `@TestPropertySource` annotations. So, in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a properties file"

It From the official docs at [2.5.1. Mapping YAML to Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.yaml.mapping-to-properties)

You might find solutions/workarounds in [Spring @PropertySource using YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml)

Comment: Thanks, I was going through one online tutorial where the guy uses application.yml, instead of application.properties and it works the same way, I thought its the same outcome for external properties as well

Comment: Yeah, sadly for PropertySource not. I usually use only application.yml and then use `@ConfigurationProperties` with a prefix to load specific configuration within that file. See https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot for a guide

Comment: Yes, @ConfigurationProperties is actually a very good utility to group a set of properties together, will make use of that, Thanks for your valuable insights.